# Please explain This output.Value of float variable do get typecast to integer.Please explain why?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define pii 3.14

void main()
{
    const float pi=3.0f;

    printf("pi= %d \n",pi);
    printf("Pi= %d",pii);
}
```

Output is :

> ```
> pi= 0
> Pi= 1374389535
> ```

I know to print float value we should use %f but why it is not typecasted in integer when we use %d.

Comment: `printf` has no way of knowing that `pi` or `pii` is not an `int`.  You have to explicitly cast them.

Comment: The compiler does as you tell it to: the `float` will be promoted to `double` as an argument for a variadic function. The compiler might look at the format string and *warn* that the type is incompatible, but only out of kindness. For example MSVC will warn about that, but not for its similar variadic function `cprintf`. It is up to the program writer to match the format specification with the arguments passed. C is like that.

Answer (score 3):

`%d` instructs `printf` to expect an `int` argument. It does not instruct the compiler to perform any conversion. The C standard does not define what happens when you pass the wrong argument type. A description of what happens in common implementations follows.

Passing arguments to a function is handled by the compiler. When you provide a `double` argument such as `pii`, it passes that argument to the routine being called as a `double` argument. When you pass a `float` argument such as `pi`, it is converted to a `double` due to rules for handling arguments to functions declared with `...` in their parameter lists.

Processing arguments is handled by `printf`. It uses the format string to know what to expect. When it sees `%d`, it attempts to read an `int`. When you have passed a `double` and not an `int`, it is not able to read an `int`—it might read the wrong data because arguments of different types are passed in different ways, and, even if it does read the right data, it will attempt to interpret the bits of that data according to the rules for `int`, not `double`.

Good compilers can observe you are calling `printf`, check the `format` string, compare it to the arguments, and warn you if there is a mismatch. (However, a compiler cannot do this in all situations because the format string might be computed during program execution rather than a constant such as `"pi= %d"`.) It is likely your compiler printed a warning message. However, if you compile and link the program in spite of the warning message, the program may misbehave in various ways.